# How to eliminate duplication with two columns in a table

Tags: sql, duplicates, row

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE T
(No1 INT,
 No2 INT
)

INSERT INTO T (No1, No2) VALUES (1, 2)

INSERT INTO T (No1, No2) VALUES (2, 1)

INSERT INTO T (No1, No2) VALUES (3, 4)

INSERT INTO T (No1, No2) VALUES (4, 3)

INSERT INTO T (No1, No2) VALUES (5, 6)

INSERT INTO T (No1, No2) VALUES (6, 5)

INSERT INTO T (No1, No2) VALUES (1, 6)

INSERT INTO T (No1, No2) VALUES (6, 1)
```

---

```
    No1 No2
    1   2 
    2   1
    3   4
    4   3
    5   6
    6   5
    1   6
    6   1
```

What I want is to eliminate rows that have the same value but in the other field. For me No1=1 No2=2 and No1=2 No2=1 is the same thing. At the end I want this as result.

```
No1 No2
1   2
3   4
5   6
1   6
```

I tried a lot of things and I did a lot of search but I find nothing. The only way I found is with a Cursor. As I play with millions of records, it is very slow. Is there a way to do this with a query?

Thank you.

Comment: What RDBMS and version? Also once you have removed the dupes you can put a unique index on `No1 No2` and a constraint on `No1 > No2` to ensure they are only stored one way round.

Comment: Is it by any chance you are checking friend requests? Coz I too have the same question! :)

Comment: When you say you want to "eliminate" the rows, are you trying to delete them from the table or just exclude them from a select statement?

Comment: @Martin that might need to be `No1 >= No2`

Comment: @RedFilter - Yes, I made an assumption there based on the example data as there are no cases where `No1 = No2`

Comment: Thank you @RedFilter. This is exactly what I was searching for :-) To Anser your question Martin, It is a SQL server 2008 R2. To anser your question Joe, I only want to exclude then form the SELECT. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.*
from MyTable t1
left outer join MyTable t2 on t1.No1 = t2.No2 and t1.No2 = t2.No1
where t2.No2 is null
    or t1.No1 <= t2.No1
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a46b9/6)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has two very useful functions for this, LEAST and GREATEST:

```
select distinct least(no1, no2), greatest(no1, no2)
from t
```